# Replace main image with thumbnail on click with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am creating a small product gallery for a product page. It currently has 4 thumbnail images and a main image. When you click on one of the thumbnail images, I would like the main image to be replaced by the clicked thumbnail image.

I have a codepen here.. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oIzqj

I feel I am close but obviously not quite there yet.

Here is my jQuery code...

```
$('.thumbnails .zoom').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();

  var photo_fullsize =  $(this).find('img').attr('src');

  $('.woocommerce-main-image img').attr('src',' + photo_fullsize + ');

});
```

Would love to see what I am missing/doing wrong.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do `$('.woocommerce-main-image img').attr('src', photo_fullsize);` instead of `$('.woocommerce-main-image img').attr('src',' + photo_fullsize + ');` and it works. See here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/uatGg

Comment: of course, I knew it was something with the syntax, thank you

Answer (score 2):

It did not work for me.

> $('.thumbnails .zoom').click(function(e){
>     e.preventDefault();

was not doing his job and was sending me to the image. I achieved the effect by modifying your code:

```
jQuery(document).on('click','.thumbnails .zoom', function(){
        var photo_fullsize =  jQuery(this).find('img').attr('src').replace('-100x132','');
        jQuery('.woocommerce-main-image img').attr('src', photo_fullsize);
        return false;
    });
```

`.replace(-100x132)` eliminates *-100x132* from the url of the image to return the full image and not the thumbnail as [blackhawk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/957186/blackhawk) explained before.

Answer (score 1):

Andrew provided a good starting point, but take it even further so that your enlarged photos have lesser pixel mess in them...

```
$('.thumbnails .zoom').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var photo_fullsize = $(this).find('img').attr('src').replace('150/200','500/500');
  $('.woocommerce-main-image img').attr('src',photo_fullsize);
});
```

...adjust the JavaScript replace() method values [500/500], to fit your needs, but test out this code for starters.

Comment: I'm confused why code uses a slash instead of an x between the image sizes? In other words why it's '150/200' and '500/500'. Shouldn't this be and x instead of a slash, since the string is: image-file-name-150x200.jpg ?

Answer (score 1):

As I already answered something very similar on WPSE...

I'm using a Regex that matches

- A non-mandatory dash
- 2-4 digits
- x-separator
- 2-4 digits

Here's the actual function. It uses the Regex as `test()` first to speed things up. Then it replaces the string before altering the actual image `src` attribute.

```
( function( $ ) {
    $( '.thumbnails .zoom' ).on( 'click', function( event ) {
        event.preventDefault();

        var $img = $( this ).find( 'img' ),
            $src = $img.attr( 'src' ),
            search = /^([-]?)([\d]{2,4})((\s*)(x)(\s*))([\d]{2,4})$/;

        // Regex .test() is fast, so we use it *before* we actually do something
        if ( search.test( $src ) {
            var $url = $src.replace( search, '' );
            $( '.class-of-the-thumbnail-image' ).attr( 'src', $url );
        }
    } );
} )( jQuery );
```

Comment: Very nice answer. Just noticed you are missing a closing bracket on the IF statement. Also had to change search REGEX to this, but only because I found it else where, my REGEX is bad. :)  
`search = /(-?)(\d{2,4})(x)(\d{2,4})/`

Comment: One other thing to add, maybe not best practice but if you want to ensure your crop size is maintained when switching images you can change `var $url = $src.replace( search, '' );` to this: `var $url = $src.replace('135x109','570x464');` ... putting in your own thumbnail and product image crop sizes of course.

Answer (score 0):

Good discussion - working with Gaston's solution above i've successfully got this working with an on hover event. But i've noticed that when a page loads, if the larger images aren't currently cached, the hover effect doesn't start working till then. Is there a method for queueing up the larger versions of the images on page load?

Answer (score 0):

just disable light box from the woocomerce settings

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    > <script>
    > 
    >  1. $('.thumbnails .zoom').click(function(e){
    >               e.preventDefault(); 
    >               var photo_fullsize =  $(this).find('img').attr('src');
    >                     var title =  $(this).find('img').attr('alt');    
    >               $('.woocommerce-main-image img').attr('src',photo_fullsize);
    >                $('.woocommerce-main-image ').attr('href',photo_fullsize);
    >         
    >                $('.woocommerce-main-image ').attr('title',title);
    >                $('.woocommerce-main-image img').attr('alt',title);
    >             });
    > 
    > </script>
```